# How to get an image to pop up when a button is clicked in a xamarin forms app?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I am working on a xamarin forms app the displays a map and when the user clicks a button the maps legend image pops up on top of the map. I am using this nuget package to get the popup effect: [Rtorgames Popup package](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)

the issue is that when I click the button the popup works but no legend image is showing up and the images are in the correct directories for both iOS and android.

heres my xaml code for the MapPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppName.Forms.Pages.Map">
    <ContentView x:Name="contentView" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MapNavBar}">
    <StackLayout>    
        <Button Text = "Legand" HorizontalOptions = "End" VerticalOptions="End" Clicked="legend_OnClicked"></Button>       
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
            <Image Source="Map.png" Scale="1.0" Aspect="AspectFit" />
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>   
    </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

here's the code behind for MapPage.xaml:

```
using System;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Extensions;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AppName.Forms.Pages
{
    public partial class Map : ContentPage
    {
        public Map()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
        }

        private async void legend_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var page = new LegendPage();

            await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(page);     
        }
    }
}
```

here's the legendPage xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             x:Class="AppName.Forms.Pages.LegendPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
            <Image Source="legend.png" Scale="1.0" Aspect="AspectFit" />
        </Grid>    
    </StackLayout>          
</pages:PopupPage>
```

and finally here's the code behind to the legendPage.xaml:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AppName.Forms.Pages
{
    public partial class LegendPage : PopupPage
    {
        public LegendPage()
        {

        }


        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
        }

        // Method for animation child in PopupPage
        // Invoced after custom animation end


        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            // Prevent hide popup
            //return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
            return true;
        }

        // Invoced when background is clicked
        protected override bool OnBackgroundClicked()
        {
            // Return default value - CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked
            return base.OnBackgroundClicked();
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: does your Map image show?  Have you verified that both images are setup identically, with the same build action?  Have you verified that the casing you're using matches the actual file?

Comment: @Jason thanks for the responce! the map shows up just fine! the legend is the one that doesn't show up any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Yes, I just gave you several suggestions.

Comment: As Jason said check you casing and build actions on image files.